# Trying to take out all ATOM from pdb file

Tags: regex, bash, shell, perl, pdb-files

Hello I am trying to take out all the lines that start with ATOM from a pdb file. For some reason, I am having trouble. My code is:

```
open (FILE, $ARGV[0])
    or die "Could not open file\n";

my @newlines;
my $atomcount = 0;
while ( my $lines = <FILE> ) {
    if ($lines =~ m/^ATOM.*/) {
    @newlines = $lines;
    $atomcount++;
}
}

print "@newlines\n";
print "$atomcount\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
 @newlines = $lines;
```

re-assigns `$lines` to the array `@newlines` and thus overwrites it with every iteration of the `while` loop.
You rather want to *append* every `$lines` to `@newlines`, so

```
push @newlines, $lines;
```

will work.

Sidenote: The variable name `$lines` should be `$line` (just for readability) because it's just *one line*, not *multiple lines*.

Instead of explicitly counting the items appended to `@newlines` (with `$atomcount++;`) you can just use the number of items in `@newlines` after the loop:

```
my @newlines;
while ( my $line = <FILE> ) {
    if ($line =~ m/^ATOM.*/) {
        push @newlines, $line;
    }
}

my $atomcount = @newlines; # in scalar context this is the number of items in @newlines
print "@newlines\n";
print "$atomcount\n";
```