# How to count each element from a pdb file

Tags: perl, pdb-files

I am having trouble trying to count the amount of each element provided in a pdb file. So far, the code has achieved to take the lines from the file that starts with ATOM. I have also gotten to the point where I can print each element. But  now I want to count each element such as C,O,N, and so on and list them in alphabetical order. 
The data looks like this:

```
 ATOM   4851  O   PRO A 715      89.164  76.083  75.292  1.00 99.41           O  
 ATOM   4852  CB  PRO A 715      88.324  78.267  73.865  1.00 95.88           C  
 ATOM   4853  CG  PRO A 715      88.836  78.838  72.540  1.00 95.93           C  
 ATOM   4854  CD  PRO A 715      90.288  78.546  72.593  1.00 94.99           C  
 ATOM   4855  N   PHE A 716      90.009  77.320  76.994  1.00100.00           N  
 ATOM   4856  CA  PHE A 716      90.100  76.203  77.966  1.00 99.66           C  
 ATOM   4857  C   PHE A 716      89.942  76.667  79.419  1.00 99.17           C  
 ATOM   4858  O   PHE A 716      88.895  76.334  80.027  1.00100.00           O  
 ATOM   4859  CB  PHE A 716      91.409  75.402  77.819  1.00 97.04           C  
 ATOM   4860  CG  PHE A 716      91.290  74.219  76.899  1.00 96.00           C  
 ATOM   4861  CD1 PHE A 716      90.323  73.236  77.133  1.00 94.17           C  
 ATOM   4862  CD2 PHE A 716      92.112  74.107  75.774  1.00 94.87           C  
 ATOM   4863  CE1 PHE A 716      90.170  72.157  76.260  1.00 93.04           C  
 ATOM   4864  CE2 PHE A 716      91.971  73.037  74.894  1.00 93.41           C  
 ATOM   4865  CZ  PHE A 716      90.996  72.057  75.137  1.00 95.29           C
```

My code is :

```
open (FILE, $ARGV[0])
    or die "Could not open file\n";

my @newlines;
while ( my $line = <FILE> ) {
    if ($line =~ m/^ATOM.*/) {
    push @newlines, $line;
    }
}

##############################################################
#This function will take out the element from each line
#The element is from column 77 and contains one or two letters
#The function will also sort each element alphabetically and count them
sub atomfreq {
    foreach my $record1(@newlines) {
      my @element = substr($record1, 76, 2);
      my @sortelement = sort(@element);
      print "@sortelement\n";
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have some input lines (10 or so) for us? If possible with different `C`, `O` and `N` columns?

Comment: ATOM   4851  O   PRO A 715      89.164  76.083  75.292  1.00 99.41           O  
 ATOM   4852  CB  PRO A 715      88.324  78.267  73.865  1.00 95.88           C  
 ATOM   4853  CG  PRO A 715      88.836  78.838  72.540  1.00 95.93           C  
 ATOM   4854  CD  PRO A 715      90.288  78.546  72.593  1.00 94.99           C  
 ATOM   4855  N   PHE A 716      90.009  77.320  76.994  1.00100.00           N

Comment: I'm sorry it came out bad. But before each ATOM you can see the element

Comment: Yes. Please [edit] your post and append them there.

Comment: Always start your Perl code with `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: Oh i have. I just put the main part of the program.

Comment: So you want to count the different values in the last column of your data?

Comment: `m/^ATOM.*/` is better written as `m/^ATOM/`. The trailing `.*` is redundant.

Comment: @borodin Yes. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47723084/5830574) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47723945/5830574) for the history of this question.

Comment: Use lexical variables (`open my $fh, ...`), not bareword filehandles (`FILE`).

Comment: What is "new" about the contents of `@newlines`?

Comment: Use three-argument open (`open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0]`), not two-argument open.

Comment: Yes. meaning if there were 7 C, 4 P, 5 N, 7 O, and so on...... then the code will out put C: 7, N: 5, O: 7, P: 5.

Comment: Include the name of the file and the reason for the failure in your error message: `die "$0: could not open $ARGV[0]: $!\n"`

Comment: `substr` returns a single string, so `@element` will only ever have one element. Sorting it is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For counting the occurences of the elements `C`, `O` and `N` (and others) a *hash* is the proper data structure.
Use the *elements* as keys and increment the corresponding value. *After* the loop you can then print the hash sorted by its keys:

```
sub atomfreq {
    my %count;
    foreach my $record1(@newlines) {
        my $element = substr($record1, 76, 2);
        $count{$element} += 1;
    }
    foreach my $element ( sort keys %count ) {
        print "element=$element, count=$count{$element}\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to `open` a file passed as a parameter on the command line: you can just read from it using `<>`. It is also much more concise to use `grep` rather a read loop, a test, and a `push`

I also don't see why you need a subroutine here

This code will do what you ask

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @lines = grep /^ATOM/, <>;

my %counts;
++$counts{ unpack '@77 A2' } for @lines;
printf "%-4s%4d\n", $_, $counts{$_} for sort keys %counts;
```

#### output

```
C     12
N      1
O      2
```

Comment: `<>` uses 2-arg open internally, which is potentially unsafe: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=258980

Comment: `grep /.../, <>` slurps the whole file into memory first, then creates a filtered copy. The `while` loop only accumulates matching lines.

Comment: @melpomene You're quite picky today ;-)

Comment: @melpomene: I don't think those are useful considerations. I'll file them along with `\d` not matching just decimal digits.

Comment: That's my secret, @PerlDuck. I'm always picky.

Comment: @Borodin we can't split in a Pdb files. Because some times spaces are not present in between two values. The better solution is we have to go with substr for a Pdb files

Comment: @mkHun: Then you need `unpack` instead. I've altered my answer.